# How to display clicked on/off SVG icon from admin panel page and display result on a different page

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I need further evolve my toggle on/off link icon that will change status by changing its background positions through classes using jquery.This link will be manipulated in a backend admin section by managers.

The jquery will also need to update the database and then reflect this chosen state/selection on a front end page for a user to see, but which cannot be changed from the user, because its just a marker to display to a user.

What I want to know, is how do I reflect this change in the front end page? Do I create another SVG background image in some default color, and then change this state through CSS from the database?

The jquery 'post' variable is pointing to a page to reflect the change (dont know how to do this in that page!), but I need to reflect this on different pages as well, not just one...

The back-end coding will be done with C#, I just need to create the foundations down for the jquery part in the front-end, but my knowledge is very limited.

I have supplied the code here with what I have so far, I just need to know with some further code, on how to reflect this change on the front-end page, because I dont know how.

I hope anyone can help me, because I am pretty desperate at this point..

```js
$('.verify').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
  $(this).toggleClass('verified');
  $.post('/yourUpdateUrl', {
      'verified': $(this).hasClass('verified'),
      'id': ID_01
    },
    function(data) {
      if (data.verified) {
        $(this).toggleClass('verified');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.verify {
  text-indent: -5000px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://imgh.us/social_4.svg');
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.verify.verified {
  background-position: 0px 38px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ID_01">
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="verify">verify</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: the best way would be to have a server sent event listner or polling using ajax done from client and from admin page toggle the value in db client can only listen to it I will show you to examples if you want

Comment: @Sachin Divakar that would be great if you showed me examples , thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Sachin Divakar can we chat?

Comment: yeah sure I have added a easy tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Server Sent Events Tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

Server-Sent Events - One Way Messaging
A server-sent event is when a web page automatically gets updates from a server.

This was also possible before, but the web page would have to ask if any

updates were available. With server-sent events, the updates come automatically.

Examples: Facebook/Twitter updates, stock price updates, news feeds, sport results, etc.

**Basically the work flow would be like this **

1. Admin changes the status of the icon from his page and database
2. Now a another page with c# periodically queries Database and broadcasts the 
   content with following format

   **event: userNameOrId\n**

   **data: {"status": "1"}\n\n**
3. Now in the client side using javascript listen to it

**OR**

Another way is to use ajax long polling method 
Example

```
  (function poll() {
       setTimeout(function() {
           $.ajax({ url: "yourpagename.aspx", success: function(data) {
                //here data contains the value returned from db
                //here check it with a if loop yes one color else one color
                 if (data.verified) {
             $(this).addClass('verified');
          }else{
            $(this).removeClass('verified');
             }
           }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
        }, 30000);
    })();
```

[Check this w3schools Demo to see how it works](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse)
[Tutorial for long polling method](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: thanks. Hmm, okay. I am just not sure if any of my code here is usable for this??

Comment: I dont have much experience with jquery, that is why I have to use forums a lot...

Comment: sorry how do I implement the ajax polling with my code I have?

Comment: @Krystyna what you have done with jquery acts directly on client side right .See what the situation you have here is that admin changes a value in Database and at client/user side you listen for such changes using a server sent event listener or ajax long polling which a change is notified you change the icon color at client/user page

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I want in regarding to the ajax polling, I just dont know how to modify the poll code to sit with my code..

Comment: @Krystyna First the server side part should be done then only client side part can be done

Comment: okay, sorry about my knowledge here...So, if I just left my jquery code to simply only toggle the link, should that be enough for the backend guy to do the rest?

Comment: @Krystyna just check the last part of my code example using ajax poll inside the function right read the comment section use the code to toggle there rest depends on server side guy and if this answer clears your question accept it as answer and upvote it.and by the way where do you work ?

Comment: See updated the  answer just copy and paste it and give your url and give your if test condition

Comment: I put this in there: `if (true){$(this).addClass('verified');} else {$(this).removeClass('verified')};`

Comment: yes its right but for checking true or false cant simply put if true

Comment: ah right. Is this correct now? `if (true){$(this).addClass('verified');} else if (false) {$(this).removeClass('verified')};`

Comment: it doesnt seem to be toggling at all: http://codepen.io/krystyna93/pen/eZxWgW?editors=0010

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if I want to keep the server connection open like this. I am completely lost, ughh

Comment: @Krystyna your code will not work as your post function have empty url field without url how will you post datat to your page and how will you expect return data to check

Comment: You seriously need to understand the concepts of jquery post and how to all works because right now what you are doing is trying to spell a word without properly learning alphabets and you are a far cry away from reading a sentence .I am not trying to insult you or anything I am trying to help you jquery post.Nobody can help you if you dont understand the concepts

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ CHECK THIS OUT START FROM IT AND USE CHROME DEVELOPER TOOLS INSIDE IT U CAN CHECK CONSOLE TO KNOW IF U HAVE ERROR IN JAVASCRIPT